# MS Project (*.mpp file) to PowerBi

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, pywin32, ms-project

I need to import data from MS-project (*.mpp file) to PowerBi.

I need free solution. So I cannot use [MS Project Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Project_Server)

I try to do it with Python. But it has many problems and it is complicated to extend it.

There is code what I use in PowerBi:

    `import win32com.client
    import pandas
    doc = 'C:\file.mpp'
    mpp = win32com.client.Dispatch("MSProject.Application")
    mpp.Visible = 1
    mpp.FileOpen(doc)
    Project = mpp.ActiveProject
    data = []
    for i in range(1,Project.Tasks.Count+1):
        if hasattr(Project.Tasks.Item(i), 'ResourceNames'):
            for c in (Project.Tasks.Item(i).ResourceNames).split(";"):
                alist= [c,Project.Tasks.Item(i).Text1,Project.Tasks.Item(i).Name]
                data.append (alist)
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data ,columns=['Resource','Customer','Task'])`

Is there any better solution?
Thanks.

Comment: What about [exporting it to Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-project-data-to-excel-ce71a2a4-e9ab-4879-a6f9-19421a70c13d) first?

Answer (score 1):

You can now connect ProjectOnline files to PowerBI.

[Link your local account](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/more-ways-to-create-or-import-projects-7c285789-52f2-4287-9ba7-27034825643f?ocmsassetID=HA102923810&CorrelationId=9adbbfcc-7527-4fca-8879-9113177e4df1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[Upload the file to your online portal](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/log-on-to-project-web-app-7e7bbf48-60dc-4a39-8f65-24f154a97028?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[MS Project online data to PowerBI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-project-online-connect-to-data)